Is it possible to type annotate Python function parameter used as TypedDict key to make mypy happy?
While working through code challenges I am trying to use type annotations for all function parameters/return types.  I use mypy in strict mode with the goal of no errors.
I've spent some time on this one and can't figure it out - example of problem:
from typing import Literal, NotRequired, TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
    Title: str
    Runtime: str
    Awards: str

class MovieData(TypedDict):
    Awards: NotRequired[str]
    Runtime: NotRequired[str]

def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Awards', 'Runtime']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    return {movie['Title']: {field: movie[field]} for movie in movies}

# Check with mypy 1.14.0:
PS> mypy --strict .\program.py
program.py:13: error: Expected TypedDict key to be string literal  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Is there some way to make this work?  I realize I can append # type: ignore to the line but I'm curious if there's another way.
I've tried a bunch of different permutations such as ensuring field matches one of the literal values before the dict comprehension but nothing seems to help.

I like @chepner's solution.  Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to make it work with mypy in strict mode - taking his example:
def get_movie_field(movies, field):
    return {movie['Title']: {field: movie[field]} for movie in movies}

I get:
PS> mypy --strict program.py
program.py:18: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

As the last get_movie_field isn't type annotated.
From reviewing the mypy docs, I updated the last get_movie_field function as follows - but it still doesn't fix the problem:
# @chepner's full solution updated with type annotations for
# last get_movie_field:
from typing import Literal, NotRequired, TypedDict, overload

class Movie(TypedDict):
    Title: str
    Runtime: str
    Awards: str

class MovieData(TypedDict):
    Awards: NotRequired[str]
    Runtime: NotRequired[str]

@overload
def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Awards']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    ...

@overload
def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Runtime']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    ...

def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Awards']|Literal['Runtime']
                    ) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    return {movie['Title']: {field: movie[field]} for movie in movies}

PS> mypy --strict program.py
program.py:19: error: Expected TypedDict key to be string literal  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

However, this inspired me to find another approach.  I'm not saying it's great but it does work in the sense that mypy doesn't complain:
from typing import Literal, NotRequired, TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
    Title: str
    Runtime: str
    Awards: str

class MovieData(TypedDict):
    Awards: NotRequired[str]
    Runtime: NotRequired[str]

def create_MovieData(key: str, value: str) -> MovieData:
    """Creates a new TypedDict using a given key and value."""
    if key == 'Awards':
        return {'Awards': value}
    elif key == 'Runtime':
        return {'Runtime': value}

    raise ValueError(f"Invalid key: {key}")

def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Awards', 'Runtime']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    return {movie['Title']: create_MovieData(field, movie[field]) for movie in movies}

PS> mypy --strict program.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file


Note it's the {field: ...} that's the problem; movie[field] is just fine. This is supposed to be supported, you should probably raise a bug/regression report.

@jonrsharpe: Using a single-option Literal type is okay, but using a Literal type with multiple options is a lot messier. In a limited set of cases (including this case), it could work, but the implementation is currently restricted to single-option Literals.

Not a bug. https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7752 - there's a low-priority FR for that, unlikely to happen anytime soon if you don't want to implement it yourself:)

@STerliakov - should chepner's solution below work?

Yes, but only because the implementation is unannotated (so for external callers it's similar to your original function, but the body is checked as def get_movie_field(movies: Any, field: Any), and at this point a #type: ignore on your original implementation is almost certainly better than this overload magic (Any is no better than ignore comment, and implicit Any is worse than an explicit one).

@STerliakov - sorry to bug you again.  If you feel like reviewing the above, I'm curious if chepner's solution with type annotations as I understand from the mypy docs should work?  It seems like this is only doing a single literal key value at a time, and I thought that should work?  Or maybe not - curious to hear your thoughts.

Overload signatures are for external callers, they are ignored when checking the function body - only the implementation signature is used for that. Implementation signature in that answer is unannotated, so all types are equivalent to Any. This works because you can do anything with Any.

You can use TypeVar to help mypy deduce the exact literal that is being used, and this can even be propagated to the output. That way mypy knows which keys are definitely present in the output dicts and which are not.
Instead of:
class MovieData(TypedDict):
    Awards: NotRequired[str]
    Runtime: NotRequired[str]

You would use:
K = TypeVar('K', Literal['Runtime'], Literal['Awards'])
# NB. NOT TypeVar('K', Literal['Runtime', 'Awards'])       -- TypeError
# AND NOT TypeVar('K', bound=Literal['Runtime', 'Awards']) -- coalesces to str

MovieData = dict[K, str]

Full example (playground):
from typing import TypedDict, TypeVar, Literal

class Movie(TypedDict):
    Title: str
    Runtime: str
    Awards: str

K = TypeVar('K', Literal['Runtime'], Literal['Awards'])

MovieData = dict[K, str]

def extract(movies: list[Movie], key: K) -> list[MovieData[K]]:
    return [{key: movie[key]} for movie in movies]

res = extract([], key='Runtime')
reveal_type(res)
# note: Revealed type is "list[dict[Literal['Runtime'], str]]"


Thank you, that works.  You've given me something to study - I don't completely understand this, I will get to work on dissecting it.

More verbose, but you can use an overload instead of a union type.
from typing import Literal, NotRequired, TypedDict, overload

class Movie(TypedDict):
    Title: str
    Runtime: str
    Awards: str

class MovieData(TypedDict):
    Awards: NotRequired[str]
    Runtime: NotRequired[str]

@overload
def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Awards']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    ...

@overload
def get_movie_field(movies: list[Movie], field: Literal['Runtime']) -> dict[str, MovieData]:
    ...

def get_movie_field(movies, field):
    return {movie['Title']: {field: movie[field]} for movie in movies}

Then
get_movie_field([], "Awards")  # OK
get_movie_field([], "Runtime")  # OK
get_movie_field([], "Foo")  # Rejected

However, the problem of type-checking the implementation of get_movie_field remains, as pointed out by STerliakov in a comment.

This is great as I was not familiar with typing.overload in Python.  Per the mypy docs on overloading, I believe you'd still want the type annotations on the final function.  Again, per the mypy docs, field would be Literal['Awards'] | Literal['Runtime'].  While I believe this should work - mypy 1.14.0 stil complains - Expected TypedDict key to be string literal.  Not sure if this is a bug or unsupported.

This is just a fancy way to spell Any in implementation - is your suggestion any better than an ignore comment? Body is only checked against the implementation signature, so in your snippet that's just def (Any, Any) -> Any which obviously passes.

I thought the type checker was supposed to ignore the implementation, per the documentation: "The non-@overload-decorated definition, meanwhile, will be used at runtime but should be ignored by a type checker."

@chepner - I see what you mean.  Here's the reference to what you quoted in the Python typing library docs.  However, the mypy docs for overloading  show mypy expects type annotations.  Is that a bug?

Hm, that's a good point (and I always forget about looking at the mypy documentation). What I show is sufficient for ensuring the call to get_movie_fields is correct, but does not type-check the body of the implementation itself.

@chepner - I created a post in the Python Discord typing channel on this.  I'll update this post once I hear back from there.

@chepner - Per Python Discord typing channel, Python typing library docs around overloads are a work-in-progress and we should use the mypy docs.  Based on that, it sounds like an overload solution doesn't work at present.  Thank you for the suggestion though - I learned a lot which I really appreciate, that's why I'm exploring type annotations.

@JamesS. and @STerliakov Good to know, and I will try to remember to check the mypy docs more often.
